# VueJS get value from input-select instead of key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My input-select as below,

```html
<input-select v-model="county" id="county" :options="getCountyList()">
  &dagger; County
</input-select>
```

My function `getCountyList()` as below,

```js
getCountyList: function () {
  var retarr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i].state_id == this.state) {
      // here STATE selected in previous drop down,
      // match it with state from json and get COUNTY
      retarr[i] = json[i].county_name;
    }
  }
  const mySet = new Set(retarr); //remove duplicates and get DISTINCT County list
  console.log("this is mySet COUNTY return array :", mySet);
  return mySet;
};
```

`console.log ("this is mySet COUNTY return array :",mySet )` returns as below:

```js
0: undefined
1: "St. Clair"
2: "Jefferson"
3: "Shelby"
4: "Tallapoosa"
5: "Blount"
6: "Talladega"
7: "Marshall"
8: "Cullman"
9: "Bibb"
10: "Chilton"
11: "Walker"
```

Now, my problem is `v-model="county"` is getting key i.e. `1`,`2`,`3` instead of COUNTY Name after selection. How can I get the COUNTY NAME there?

Comment: @RajestPandhare is input-select made by you? please show us the implementation of input-select

Comment: @Dalvik input-select is the same as select, no change.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
getCountyList: function(){
   var retarr=[]; 
      for (let i=0; i< json.length; i++){
        if (json[i].state_id == this.state ) { // here STATE selected in previous drop down, 
match it with state from json and get COUNTY
               retarr[i] = {text: json[i].county_name, value: json[i].county_name};
            }
      }
    

      return retarr;
  
}
```

You don't need set in this, as there will be no duplicates. because of object.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a clean way of filtering and getting the selected option from the `select` field in `vuejs`.

##### Points to note:

1. Use computed properties for filtering out or manipulating reactive properties in `vue`
2. Use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) for filter out duplicates from array. `lodash` has a plethora of methods for manipulating arrays and you don't need to write code for handling all the complex logic.
3. There's absolutely no need for you to loop over the array and then create another array and filter that out using `Set`. That's just a lengthy way of doing it.
4. You can bind the entire item object to the `option`'s value and access it's properties later, like I've shown below.
5. Try and use `camelCase` naming convention for naming variables in vue.
6. Try and use `const` and `let` as per the new `ES6` standards.

###### P.S: Expand snippet below and run it!

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      country: '',
      json: [
        { stateId: 1, countryName: "St. Clair" },
        { stateId: 2, countryName: "Jefferson" },
        { stateId: 3, countryName: "Shelby" },
        { stateId: 4, countryName: "Tallapoosa" },
        { stateId: 5, countryName: "Blount" },
        { stateId: 6, countryName: "Talladega" },
        { stateId: 7, countryName: "Marshall" },
        { stateId: 8, countryName: "Cullman" },
        { stateId: 9, countryName: "Bibb" },
        { stateId: 10, countryName: "Chilton" },
        { stateId: 11, countryName: "Walker" },
        { stateId: 1, countryName: "St. Clair" }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    countries() {
      return _.uniqBy(this.json, "countryName");
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="country" id="county">
      <option
        v-for="item in countries"
        :key="item.stateId"
        v-bind:value="item"
      >
        {{ item.countryName }}
      </option>
    </select>

    <span>Selected Country: ID: {{country.stateId}} Name: {{ country.countryName }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Salvino , your explanation cleared my basics, I am evaluating the answer right now. My additional requirement is whenever the STATE drop down gets selected a new state, the COUNTY dropdown should populate counties for that STATE. I am trying your suggestion to accommodate this requirment.